# How to get number of elements of string array via a pointer to a pointer

Tags: c++

**See Last line of code:**
Trying to get number of elements from a array depending on a condition. How do i get the number of elements in an array when using an array like shown below:

```
using namespace std;
const char *options[3] = {"Option1", "Option2", "Option3"};
const char *options2[2] = {"Option1", "Option2"};

int main() {
  const char **p;

  if (true) {
    p = options;
  } else {
    p = options2;
  }

  printf("%ld\n", sizeof(options));               // returns 24
  printf("%ld\n", sizeof(options2));              // Returnns 16
  printf("%ld\n", sizeof(options) / sizeof(p));   // returns 3
  printf("%ld\n", sizeof(options2) / sizeof(p));  // returns 2

  // How to use only pointer p to get the number of elements
  printf("%ld\n", sizeof(p) / sizeof(p[0]));  // returns 1 and not 3
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dividing `sizeof(options)` by `sizeof(p)` doesn't make sense.  It's a different pointer type from `*options`.  Sure, it may give the desired result, but it's extremely misleading.  Use `sizeof(options) / sizeof(*options)`.  As for using `p` to get the size, you can't.  `p` is just a pointer.  Its size doesn't depend on its value.  `sizeof(p)/sizeof(p[0])` is going to be `sizeof(char **)/sizeof(char *)`, which is a constant, and is going to be `1` on any normal architecture.

Comment: I think it's impossible in C. There might be a way to do it in C++, by means of a template trick.

Comment: C++ is not C. Please don't tag C.

Comment: What you're asking for is not possible (not in C that is, I didn't notice you're using C++). `options` and `options2` are statically declared arrays, but `p` is declared simply as a pointer and stores no information about the memory it is pointing to, and `sizeof(p)` just returns the size of an integer.

Comment: It is simply not possible to get an array's size from just a raw pointer to an array element. Not in C, not in C++. Period.

Comment: You don't have a *pointer-to-pointer*, you have two *arrays-of-pointers* to string-literals. Since you have an *array-of-pointers* the element size with simple be `sizeof (a_pointer)`. The size of the array is still `sizeof array / sizeof *array`. To get the length of each string literal, you will need to use a string function (like `strlen()` or use a simply loop) Now `char *name[size]` is an *array-of-pointers*. `char (*name)[size]` is a *pointer-to-array*. In either case `&name` would be a *pointer-to-pointer*. All three types are different.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - you can get the array size, you can't get the size of what each pointer points to (which won't be in the array anyway in the case of string-literals)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "*you can get the array size*" - no, you can't. All size information is lost when using a raw pointer to an array element. There is no way at all to extract the array size via such a pointer. Which is exactly what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @RemyLebeau a pointer is a fixed size on any OS. If you have an array of them, it's no different than having an array of `int`. You can get the number of elements with `size_t nelem = sizeof array / size_of *array;` and the size of the array `size_t arrsize = nelem * sizeof (a_pointer);` I think we are saying the same thing. I'm not talking about the thing pointed to by the element of the array, I'm talking about the array-of-pointers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see the issue, you are talking about `p` and I'm talking about `option` and `option2`. No way to get the array size with `p` in C or C++, but you very surely can get the size of `option` and `option2`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "*you are talking about `p`*" - yes, because that is what the OP specifically asked about. "*I'm talking about `option` and `option2`*" - that was never in question. And the OP already knew about the `sizeof` calculation you mentioned, since it is shown in the OP's code. "*No way to get the array size with `p` in C or C++*" - exactly, and THAT is the OP's actual question.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but it is simply not possible to get an array's size from just a raw pointer to an array element.

One option is to store the array size in a separate variable alongside the array pointer, eg:

```
#include <iostream>

const char *options[3] = {"Option1", "Option2", "Option3"};
const char *options2[2] = {"Option1", "Option2"};

int main() {
  const char **p;
  size_t p_size;

  if (some condition is true) {
    p = options;
    p_size = sizeof(options) / sizeof(options[0]); // or better: std::size(options) in C++17 and later
  } else {
    p = options2;
    p_size = sizeof(options2) / sizeof(options2[0]); // or better: std::size(options2)
  }

  std::cout << sizeof(options) << "\n"; // returns 24
  std::cout << sizeof(options2) << "\n"; // returns 16
  std::cout << p_size << "\n"; // returns 3 or 2, based on condition

  return 0;
}
```

In C++20 and later, you can use `std::span`  instead (in C++14 and C++17, you can use `gsl::span` from the [GSL library](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL)), eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <span>

const char *options[3] = {"Option1", "Option2", "Option3"};
const char *options2[2] = {"Option1", "Option2"};

int main() {
  std::span<const char*> p;

  if (some condition is true) {
    p = options;
  } else {
    p = options2;
  }

  std::cout << sizeof(options) << "\n"; // returns 24
  std::cout << sizeof(options2) << "\n"; // returns 16
  std::cout << p.size() << "\n"; // returns 3 or 2, based on condition

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to write C++, write C++. You're starting from one of C's more questionable decisions, and then trying to force C++ to do the same thing. To twist Nike's phrase, "Just don't do it!"

```cpp
std::array<char const *, 3> options {"Option1", "Option2", "Option3"};
std::array<char const *, 2> options2 {"Option1", "Option2"};
```

This makes it easy to retrieve the size of the array in question--and the size is part of the type, so all the work happens at compile time, so it imposes no runtime overhead. For example, if you do something like this:

```cpp
template <class Array>
void showSize(Array const &a) {
    std::cout << a.size() << "\n";
}

int main() { 
    showsize(options);
    showSize(options2);
}
```

...what you'll find is that the compiler just generates code to write out the literal 3 or 2:

```
    mov     esi, 3    // or `mov esi, 2`, in the second case
    call    std::operator<<(std::ostream &, unsigned long)
```

[I've done a bit of editing to demangle the name there, but that's what the code works out to.]

Here's the [un-edited version](https://godbolt.org/z/f4Tj6njMP), in case you care.

If you really insist, you can side-step using an `std::array` as well:

```cpp
const char *options[3] = {"Option1", "Option2", "Option3"};
const char *options2[2] = {"Option1", "Option2"};

template <class T, size_t N>
void showSize(T (&array)[N]) {
    std::cout << N << '\n';
}

int main() {
    showSize(options);
    showSize(options2);
}
```

This doesn't actually use a pointer though--it passes the array by reference, which retains its type information, so the instantiated function template "just knows" the size of the array over which it was instantiated.

20 years ago, I'd have said this was a good way to do things. 10 years ago, I'd have preferred `std::array`, but realized it was new enough some compilers didn't include it yet. Nowadays, unless you really need to use an ancient (Pre-C++ 11) compiler, I'd use `std::array`.

Comment: Thanks for the indepth explanation. I come from a C/embedded C environment where I have not used more of the tradtinal solutions used in C++. This made things more easy to understand. I will need to review my codebase and see where I can improve on this. Thanks <3